# Determine public Amazon EC2 instance IP address from instance ID

Tags: php, amazon-ec2

We're writing a PHP script that creates and starts an Amazon EC2 instance. We would like to determine the public IP address of the instance we're creating from PHP. Is there an API function for doing this? I was able to find [Instance.getPublicIpAdress() for Java](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/Instance.html#getPublicIpAddress%28%29), but have been unable to find a similar function for PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using the [AWS SDK for PHP](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/)?  If so, I think you can do something like the following:

```
$response = $ec2_account->describe_instances();

foreach ($response->body->reservationSet->item as $item)
{
  $ipAddress = (string) $item->instancesSet->item->ipAddress;
}
```

This obviously returns *every* EC2 instance, not just the one you want, so you would need to refine it a bit.  Unfortunately, I'm not really a PHP guy, so that's left as an exercise for the reader :-).

You can find the documentation for `describe_instances()` [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonEC2/describe_instances).

**EDIT:** I *think* this will look something like:

```
$response = $ec2_account->describe_instances(array("InstanceId"->"i-123456"));
```

But again, not a PHP guy.

Answer (score 4):

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
```

Comment: Mind explaining? Or atleast linking to something that explains? http://serverfault.com/a/427022/129574

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']`?

---

Edit: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/index.html?concepts.html

> To determine your instance's public and private IP addresses
>
> Construct the following Query request.
>
> https://ec2.amazonaws.com/?Action=DescribeInstances&InstanceId.1=**instance-id**&**...authparameters...**

This will give an XML response. To determine the public IP address, use the IP address specified within `ipAddress` in that response.

You could do something like this with CURL.

Comment: No, that would give me the IP address of the web server, I want the IP address of the EC2 instance the web server starts.

Comment: I don't think this will work without a valid signature (see http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/index.html?using-query-api.html).  That's why I recommend using the Amazon SDK, or something similar, instead.

Answer (score 1):

The following should get you the full instance description for an instance with an id of 'instance-id'

```
$response = $ec2Client->describeInstances(array('InstanceIds' => array('instance-id')));
```

and the following will grab the public ip from the instance

```
echo $response->get('Reservations')[0]['Instances'][0]['PublicIpAddress']
```

Comment: I just tested this code and the PublicIpAddress field is missing from my call, but that's probably because in the console, my instances don't have public IP addresses, so your mileage may vary.